# visual studio 2008 c# compiler error ( I am not sure)

Tags: c#

Visual studio 2008, .net 3.5 and SP1
When debugging i get an weird exception. The debugger jumps to some code to which ( i believe ) it shouldn't and as a result i get the following situation:
https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/Z5sX

DisplayMember is empty but it should be "Name". Its like everything is shifted by one line of the debugger.

https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/Z5sb

and the weird thing is that this problem goes away if i remove a certain line of code in another place which has nothing to do with the one you see on the pictures. Its like there are invisible lines of code which are causing the debugger to jump around.

Comment: Can you please show your work and exception/error message as a text?

Comment: Try a clean solution and rebuild all.

Comment: Also make sure you're using a non-optimized Debug build when stepping-through rather than an optimized or Release build, as the compiler will remove and re-order instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I already had this problem. The problem is that your project is pointing to one assembly that not corresponding to your code. 
Try clean and rebuild, also verify the path of your reference to be sure that you're pointing to correct one reference.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the suggestions. It was not the rebuild nor the clean that helped.

I actually did have a mistake in my code which was called by the two lines mentioned in the pictures i posted ( i was not aware that those lines call other methods and that was the first cause :)):

```
 string commandtext = string.Format("Select tp0op from tp0 where tp0pk = '{1}' ", brojdokumentaint);
```

i put {1} instead of {0} in the string which caused the strange behavior.

the correct code of course would be :

```
 string commandtext = string.Format("Select tp0op from tp0 where tp0pk = '{0}' ", brojdokumentaint);
```

So if you are experiencing similar behavior , review your strings :). 
Good Luck